# How to evaluate the following ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose that a hazard function is described by:
$$
\phi(t)=\frac{-\mathcal{R}'(t)}{\mathcal{R}(t)}
$$
if $\phi(t)=16t^3$, how to evaluate $\mathcal{R}(t)$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that

$$(\ln(R))'=\frac {R'}R$$
Therefore
$$\phi(t)=\frac{-\mathcal{R}'(t)}{\mathcal{R}(t)}$$
$$16t^3=\frac{-\mathcal{R}'(t)}{\mathcal{R}(t)}$$
$$\ln(R)=-16\int t^3dt$$
$$\ln(R)=-4{t^4}+K$$
$$ \implies R(t)=Ke^{- 4{t^4}}$$

Comment: Many thanks for your help!

Comment: @Yuteng you're welcome...